# run activity at particular date and time in Android

Tags: android, scheduling

how can i schedule particular activity to run at particular **DATE and TIME fields of database?**

for example send email on someone's birthday automatically..

hope for some code snippet.

--
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a Service. It is an activity that runs in the background and doesn't require user interaction.

You can have the Service check the db everyday and compare it to the current date then send an email if it is the correct date.

This explains Services more: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

and here is an example of how to code a service with a timer:

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx

Goodluck

Comment: Thanks buddy. My other query is if I implement service as you suggested then it compares today's date and db's date continually i think. Do it load the device?

Comment: It will run in the background so no it won't put a heavy load on the device. You should make it run once a day.

Comment: Service is activity? no. Service is 1 of 4 component in Android App. Activity is another component. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#Components